# Estimating Unique Population Sizes

Tags: bayesian, sampling, resampling

I am trying to estimate the total number of unique visitors to my website.

My website contains 500 different pages.

I am able to:

1. find the number of unique users to a given page
2. find the number of unique users to a collection of up to 200 pages

What would be the best method of estimating the total number of unique visitors to the total website?

My idea so far is to sample many different combinations of 200 pages of the total site and try to determine the likelihood of overlaps between samples - however I'm not sure how to actually implement this.

Can anyone tell me an acceptable method?

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on point 2? Does that mean that you can choose up to 200 pages and determine how many unique users visited them in a given time interval? Are these 200 pages representative of the whole website?

Comment: I can choose any 200 pages and determine the overall number of unique visitors in a given time period. So if user A visits page X and Page Y, method 1.) would count this as two unique visitors, but method 2.) with pages X and Y in the same group would count 1 unique visitor. I cannot choose a collection of 200 pages such that it is a representative sample of the whole website.

Comment: The technique for estimating population sizes from several incomplete lists is called [Multiple Systems Estimation](https://hrdag.org/2013/03/11/mse-the-basics/). It seems to me that it should apply to your situation too.