# Estimate number of duplicate items in a population by sampling

Tags: probability, estimation, sampling, population

I have a data source that allows me to pull big sets of numbers (~1e12) with unknown distribution.
let's define *Mostly distinct* as more than *MD* percent of the population is distinct numbers.

For each population, I need to decide if it is *Mostly distinct* or not, how can I estimate the probability of *Mostly distinct* of the population based on the sample?
How does the confidence interval changes based on the sample size?

i.e.

Population size: 1000

MD = 0.99 (99%)

sample: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9] (size=10, 9 distinct values)

How can decide if the original population is *Mostly distinct* hence have more than 990 (1000*MD) distinct values? What is the confidence interval for that?

I've seen those questions that are near but not exactly my issue plus, most of them are unanswered:

[Estimate number of unique items by number of duplicates in a sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193973/estimate-number-of-unique-items-by-number-of-duplicates-in-a-sample)

[Estimating population size from the frequency of sampled duplicates and uniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9240/estimating-population-size-from-the-frequency-of-sampled-duplicates-and-uniques)

[Estimating Unique Population Sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435006/estimating-unique-population-sizes)

[Estimating population size from the frequency of sampled duplicates and uniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9240/estimating-population-size-from-the-frequency-of-sampled-duplicates-and-uniques)

Comment: I believe the law of large number will be helpful here

Comment: I understand your populations are already coded in a database, so if this is small there should be no need of sampling or estimation, just count the number of unique members exactly. But: Can you clarify: Is your databas(es) the complete populations? Are they all very large? distributed? Is there restrictions on how you can do the samplig? (maximal sample size, batch sizes, ...)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen the population can come from a variety of sources. The population can be huge (sometimes hundreds of billions) and for huge populations - resources related restrictions prevent me from processing them all- that's why I need estimation. The set is a complete instance of something. It is not distributed.